# vb.net class upcasting / downcasting

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I'm having an issue with casting classes in vb.net, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with the Compact Framework 3.5 as I'm working on legacy Windows Mobile project.

I have a DLL which acts as the Data Layer for accessing Database objects in SqlCe and I cant change any of the code in there, however I want to add extra functionality to the exposed classes for the Business logic so I created my own classes and Inherited the classes from the Data Layer

```vb
Public Partial Class Customers
    Public Function ListAll() As IEnumerable(Of Customers)
        'Do Work
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyCustomers
    Inherits Customers

    Public Function FindCustomer(ID As Integer)
    End Function
End Class
```

so in my code I would write something like

```vb
For Each c As MyCustomer In Customers.ListAll
    'I want to be able to use my c.FindCustomer(), but I get an InvalidCast Exception above.
Next
```

I get that this is an issue with upcasting / downcasting (I don't remember which way is which), but how can I solve it ?

I can't change the return type of `Customers.ListAll()` but I need to be able to add methods and properties to implement the business logic.

Comment: `Public Function FindCustomer(ID as integer) ...`, the return type would be `As Customers` (plural? You have in `Customers`: `ListAll() As IEnumerable(of Customers)`, returning an Enumerable of itself). If you have Linq's extension there, you could `Return ListAll().FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.ID = ID)`. If not, looping `Me.ListAll()`.

Comment: Maybe my example wasn't the best...

Comment: That will never work since the variable wasn't created as a MyCustomers (imagine if you had class variable, where would they go). Your only option seem to be using Extensions but I'm not sure if they exists in 3.5. You would still not have access to private variables.

Comment: [Partial classes cannot span multiple assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#restrictions) so your partial class Customers isn't the same as the one in the DLL. Or maybe I misunderstood...

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Customers` in `For Each c As MyCustomer In Customers.ListAll`? It's confusing if it's named the same as the class. It's almost like your `ListAll` is a static method. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, guys it does not return itself. I made a mistake when trying to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside the `For Each` loop:**

For a one-shot:

```
DirectCast(c, MyCustomer).FindCustomer(1) 'for id 1
```

To use more than one time:

```
Dim customer as MyCustomer = DirectCast(c, MyCustomer)
customer.FindCustomer(1)
```

You can also do:

```
With DirectCast(c, MyCustomer)
    .FindCustomer(1)
    .AnotherMethod()
    'etc
End With
```

Have fun!

---

Here's an alternative. I'm not sure of the exact architecture of your project, so I'll assume it's like this:

```
Customers      -has a list of Customer
MyCustomers    -child of Customers with a list of MyCustomer and more functionalities

Customer       -base entry
MyCustomer     -base entry with more functionalities
```

The problem being that you cannot cast an object into it's child (this sort of operation can only work in the other direction), this is basically an impossible problem. Yet you can bypass it with some cloning. This tells me that the base data is the same for `Customer` and `MyCustomer`, you only added more methods. Which is great, because it also means that you can manually transform a Customer into a MyCustomer. You just need it to happen automatically.

In the MyCustomers and MyCustomer class, you can add theses:

```
'In MyCustomers
Public Shared Function GetMyCustomersFromCustomers(customers As Customers) As MyCustomers
    Dim data As New MyCustomers()
    'copy each modal variable

    'create a list of MyCustomer from existing Customer list
    For Each c As Customer In customers.listOfCustomers
            data.listOfMyCustomers.Add(MyCustomer.GetMyCustomerFromCustomer(c))
    Next

    Return data
End Function

'In MyCustomer
Public Shared Function GetMyCustomerFromCustomer(customer As Customer) As MyCustomer
    Dim data As New MyCustomer

    'copy all the data

    Return data
End Function
```

Then if you want to work with your own objects you can extrapolate them from the ones of the dll:

```
'let's say you currently have a 'customers' as Customers object
Dim myStuff as MyCustomers = MyCustomers.GetMyCustomersFromCustomers(customers)
```

If you often need the MyCustomers list and don't care about the rest of the class, you can create a `Shared` function which gives you only the extrapolated list of MyCustomer, no problem.

This works only as long as you can extrapolate MyCustomer from Customers and MyCustomer from Customer, of course.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the cast still fails when using Direct Cast, Customers.ListAll() returns an IEnumerable(of Customer), so can't be directly cast to MyCustomer even though MyCustomer inherits Customer.

Comment: Can you modify the return type or add another function for this kind of use? Or is that part in the dll?

Comment: I can modify the DLL, but the souce code is generated from a tool so with any DB changes I would lose my changes. The DB list functions all return a IEnumerable(of)

Comment: So you can access it but any modification would be pointless?

Comment: Yes. I've managed to get a fix / workaround by passing the object into my class and cloning it. I'm not sure if there is a better way ?

Comment: That's resourceful. Does `Customers.ListAll()` really returns a list of itself, or does it return a list of some other class (probably names `Customer`)? I know it seems trivial but it mess with my head.

Comment: Looking at the code it does not return a list of itself, I tried to simplify the sample but made that mistake.

Comment: If there are no more ideas, do I just post my own answer as the solution ?

Comment: That would be a good idea, as it might profit a futur reader. Also, I added a bypass method to the end of my answer just in case it might be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your input. I ended up writing an Extension method "convert" for the ToList method.

Comment: @henda79 I like your idea better than mine actually. Cheers!

Comment: @henda79 Does this version of VS / .NET have `Cast`?